# Why is writing unsigned char* to binary files using ofstream is slower than expected?

Tags: c++, performance, ofstream, file-writing

I created a function which saves unsigned char* data to a binary file. The process is realized in a separate thread and is supposed to append the data received from a queue (boost::lockfree::queue). My SSD drive is theoretically capable of write speeds up to ~5000MB/s, however I noticed that it hardly ever exceeds 500MB/s. I am on Windows platform if that matters. What could be the bottleneck in the code below?

*Setup: camera feed --> image acquisition board --> write data to memory --> queue data using boost::lockfree::queue --> pop data on demand --> save to a binary file*

```
void SaveData::saveAsBinary(std::string filePath, DataFeed *d)
{
    saveThreadADone = false;    // std::atomic<bool> flag

    std::thread storeDataThread([this, filePath, d] {

    std::ofstream file = open(filePath, std::ios::beg | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::ate | std::ofstream::binary);
    if(outputFile.fail()){
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open file for saving.");
        }
   
        while(!d->isDataEmpty()) // Assume data collection is already done
        {           
            auto bufferData = d->getData().get(); // getData returns std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>
            size_t bufferDataSize = sizeof (bufferData);
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(bufferData), bufferDataSize);
            if (!file.good())
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("There was an error while saving buffer data to file.");
            }
        }
        file.close();
        this->saveThreadADone = true;
    });

    storeDataThread.join();
}

std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> DataFeed::getData()
{
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> output(nullptr);

    if(!dataQueue.empty()){ // boost::lockfree::queue<unsigned char*> dataQueue {100}
        dataQueue.pop(output);
    }
    return output;
}

bool DataFeed::isDataEmpty()
{
    return dataQueue.empty();
}

// Somewhere else in the code
saveData_->saveAsBinary("specifiedPath", *dataFeed);
```

Comment: 1) What's the point of starting a new thread and then joining it? 2) I wonder how big the buffers are? Perhaps you're wasting too much time getting the buffers? Is it more like a million buffers with 5 bytes or 5 buffers with a million bytes?

Comment: to expand on 1, `thread t1{ [](){ ...}}; t1.join();` adds the overhead of creating and joining a thread, but no concurrency to your code

Comment: I agree with @user253751: Starting and joining threads is expansive. Instead, I would consider to start a thread from the beginning and using a `std::condition_variable` to trigger activation. Thus, the thread will sleep until it's needed. I already did "file dumping in the background" this way. I cannot tell you the actual data rate. In my case,  it just was fast enough. Hence, I didn't analyze further...

Comment: To explain further: suppose the thread is detached so it can do the task in the background. I can read the buffer size information from hardware and it reports that a single image will occupy 5242880 bytes. What I am saving is images one by one. Depending on user decision there can be either a few or a lot of them captured.

Comment: _suppose the thread is detached_ Why do you want to detach the thread? A detached thread cannot be joined anymore which takes away the option to tear it down in a controlled way whenever it's not needed anymore. I'm not aware of any performance advantage of a detached over a joinable thread (at least, as long as it's just running).

Comment: Note that `lockfree` doesn't mean wait-free. You should time your SDD performance on the data that is ready, like write the same image 100 times.